# Is the "auto director" startup avoidable?

Tags: happy-action-theatre

In Double Fine's Happy Action Theatre, the game automatically starts in a "director" mode, which automatically cycles through scenes. This is usually fine, but sometimes I just want to go straight to a particular scene. I've figured out that I can wait till the game starts in director mode, then pause it and manually select the scene I want. The problem is this involves several long load times and I'm impatient. The spotlights that appear during load up appear interactive, but I haven't been able to figure out how to stop the director from being selected. Is there a shortcut to avoid the director mode on start up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my experience and research, **no, the director is not skippable**.  In the end it's probably better that way, since it makes the game easy to use for kids which I think was a primary intent.